# How to select range of an image sequence with sequential suffixes in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 100 images (001.png ... 100.png) in my img folder and I want to create 2 gif files with different frame ranges for specific uses from there.

The first case uses all 100 images. I use the code below and it works fine.
`ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 30 -i %003d.png -vf scale=-2:480 myAnim.gif`

But in the second case, we want to use only 50 images from 20 to 70. What code should I use to select this specific range?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the starting image, see the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1), specifically:

```
start_number
Set the index of the file matched by the image file pattern to start 
to read from. Default value is 0.
```

For the end, you need to use the `-t` duration input option to control it. If you have 50 images at 30 fps, it'll take 1-2/3 seconds, so put down `-t 1.67` (round up to be on the safe side).